# Как в python вывести значения списка по условию через pandas или numpy

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

Пусть есть список `res = [0, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 3, 6, 8, 1]`
По условию нужно вывести те элементы списка которые удовлетворяют условию: должно быть `< 3`
Нужен именно метод из pandas или numpy

Знаю только `np.array(res) < 3` , но в таком случае он выведет не элементы, а только булевы значения `True\False`, а нужно именно сами значения

Answer (score 2):

Дальше просто нужно применить этот булев массив в качестве индексатора к массиву данных. И в `Numpy` и в `Pandas` будет практически одинаково:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

res = [0, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 3, 6, 8, 1]
arr = np.array(res)
print(arr[arr < 3])
ser = pd.Series(res)
print(ser[ser < 3].values)
```

Вывод:

```
[0 2 2 1]
[0 2 2 1]
```

От `Pandas.Series` я ещё взял `.values`, потому что иначе ещё индексы элементов напечатаются, будет не так наглядно выглядеть.

Comment: `Дальше просто нужно применить ...`. Такое чувство, что начало текстов куда то пропало.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, простейший вариант (без нумпи) такой:

```
res = [0, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 3, 6, 8, 1]
result = [st for st in res if st>3]
print(result)
```

С использованием нумпи это выглядит несколько сложнее, но и возможностей больше:

```
import numpy as np
 
values = np.array([0, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 3, 6, 8, 1])
conditions = values > 3
print(conditions)
result =  values[conditions]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Однострочник на `pandas`. Делаем серию, фильтруем (отбираем) через `loc[]` с лямбдой. В лямбде `lt(3)` означает **l**ess **t**hen (меньше чем) 3. Потом переводим в список и печатаем.

```
print(pd.Series([0, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 3, 6, 8, 1]).loc[lambda x: x.lt(3)].tolist())
```

```
[0, 2, 2, 1]
```